# A rhyming riddle: Drab and gray, / Solid and rough, / Throw it away / Without second thought

Tags: riddle

Another riddle I made:

> Drab and gray,
> Solid and rough,
> Throw it away
> Without second thought.
> But beneath the surface,
> A mineral treasure is hid.
> Forged in thunder and fire,
> Or by water and fluid.
> What am I?

So what is the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like the answer is

> A geode

> Drab and gray,
> Solid and rough,

> Geodes are usually like rocks, somewhat boring on the outside.

> Throw it away
> Without second thought.

> To break open a geode, you can throw it hard on an even harder surface, in that case the ground. Some people prefer using tools to avoid damaging it more than needed.

> But beneath the surface,
> A mineral treasure is hid.

> Geodes often contain mineral formations on their inside, [look](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/WLANL_-_Urville_Djasim_-_Geode_amethist_-_Amethyst_geode_%282%29.jpg/492px-WLANL_-_Urville_Djasim_-_Geode_amethist_-_Amethyst_geode_%282%29.jpg)

> Forged in thunder and fire,
> Or by water and fluid.

> Geodes are usually volcanic rocks filled with minerals, the latter formed by dissolution of mineral-rich fluids, the "thunder" part may refer to some geodes being born of [fulgurite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgurite)